# How to plot discrete lines instead of bars?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have plotted a histogram. But I want to plot discrete lines instead of three bars. Is there any way to do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
w1 = [-2,-2,-2,-2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
n,bins,patches = plt.hist(w1,bins=10)
plt.xlabel("bins")
plt.ylabel("counts")
plt.show()
```

Comment: ```n,bins,patches = plt.hist(w1,bins=50,width=0.03)```

Answer (score 1):

#### If you just want to plot bars with smaller width

Use the argument `rwidth`, for relative width of each histogram bar compared to the bin size. Experiment different values for different visual results. Example:

```
w1=[-2,-2,-2,-2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
n,bins,patches=plt.hist(w1,bins=10, rwidth=0.1) 
plt.xlabel("bins") 
plt.ylabel("counts") 
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### If you actually want to plot lines instead of bars

Loop over each value inside `w1` and call `plt.plot` on a line from XY (value, 0) to XY (value, number of times value appears in `w1`). Example:

```
for value in w1: 
    plt.plot([value, value], [0, w1.count(value)], color='b') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that I've used the argument `color='b'` so that matplotlib wouldn't make different colors for each line. Also, by default matplotlib adds some whitespace to surrounding lines when we call `plt.plot`, so you may want to call `plt.ylim(bottom=0)`, so that the bars do not appear to "float" above the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `plt.hist(...)` ad a variable: `rwidth` (relative width) with a value bellow 1, that way you will get bars with lower width.

Read more about that here: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use a stem plot with the counts of the unique elements of the data. Of course this only makes sense for discrete data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w1 = [-2,-2,-2,-2,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
u, c = np.unique(w1, return_counts=True)
plt.stem(u,c, use_line_collection=True, basefmt="none")
plt.ylim(0,None)
plt.xlabel("bins")
plt.ylabel("counts")
plt.show()
```

[image]